# The stepper control in the collectionView ，how to get the rowindex in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, collectionview, stepper

The stepper control in the collectionView，When the ValueChanged event be triggered ，Can I get the rowindex?

My question is as same as "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737450/how-to-get-selected-indexpath-from-a-stepper-located-inside-a-collection-view-ce"

,but It is the ios swift soulution. In the Xamarin programming ,I have no idea how to do it ?

Comment: Do exactly what the other solution says.  Assign the index value to the stepper's Tag property when you create the cell.  In your stepper event handler check the value of that property to get the index value.

Comment: Hi Jason, but in the Xamarin programming, there is no tag property in stepper control~

Comment: All controls that inherit from UIView have a Tag property.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiview.tag?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#UIKit_UIView_Tag

Comment: Maybe it is for the Xamarin iOS，but I always use the Shared projects to develope(both for iOS,Android).
add the Tag property to the stepper control，It is really can not be compiled~

Comment: Your question is not tagged as Xamarin Forms, you do not mention Xamarin Forms anywhere in your question, you did not include any code in your question that would allow me to infer what you were doing, and the question you linked to as "the same" is specifically for iOS.

Comment: Hi Jason, sorry for my negligence~

Comment: I notice this discuss "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734792/xamarin-forms-listview-stepper-binding"
is also releative to the question. Maybe In xamarin-forms this question Can't be resolved~

Comment: Do you actually need the index value, or do you just need a reference to the object the cell is bound to?

Comment: Maybe the MVVM can figure out this problem~
I am trying~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your `CollectionView`'s `ItemsSource` is a `List<Widget>` then each cell will be bound to a single `Widget` and you can reference the related widget in the event handler.  You don't need the index of the row, you can directly reference the bound object

```
void ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  var stepper = (Stepper)sender;
  var widget = (Widget)stepper.BindingContext;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Jason,This answer has figuring out the problem!